# wxPython: Changing to other panel in the frame hides the first panel, but displays a tiny box at the top left corner instead of the other panel

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, desktop-application

My app frame contains a default large panel and two sub-panels inside it. When clicking on a particular menu-item, I want this default panel to change to another panel. My code:

This is the main frame shown when the app is opened. It contains one panel, which also contains two more panels:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title="My Sample App.", size=(1280, 720))

        self.InitMenuBar()
        self.home_panel = HomePanels(self)

    def InitMenuBar(self):
        # Create Menu Bar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        # Create File Menu
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        about_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, 'About', 'Show About')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_about, about_item)
        quit = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit', 'Close')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, quit)

        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Center()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def on_about(self, event):
        # Show the About panel and hide the Main panel
        self.about_panel = AboutPanel(self)
        self.home_panel.Hide()
        self.about_panel.Show()

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Below is the panel that's holding two sub-panels in the main frame:

```
class HomePanels(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Left panel-----------------------------------------------------
        left_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE, size=(250, 600))
        left_panel.SetBackgroundColour('blue')
        main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 1)

        # Right panel-----------------------------------------------------
        right_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
        right_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#f8f8ff')
        main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 1, wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, 2)

        self.Center()
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()
```

My `AboutPanel.py`. This is what I want to replace with the `HomePanel` panel when the `About` option in the `File` menu is clicked on:

```
class AboutPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        about_main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        abt_text = wx.StaticText(self, label="About Panel", pos=(10, 10))
        about_main_sizer.Add(abt_text, 1, wx.EXPAND, 2)
        
        self.SetSizer(about_main_sizer)
```

Running this code produces this output:
[image: output-whole]

And clicking on the `About` option in `File` menu produces this output:
[image: output-error]

I can't figure out the problem! What's causing the `About` panel to appear like this?

Comment: I've answered your question, but it is still not a minimal reproducible example. I had to add the wx main loop and mainframe.Show(). I should just have to copy your code and run it, not have to work out why nothing is shown

Comment: Oh no, I missed adding the `MainLoop()`! That's why the code wasn't reproducible for this long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does it. The problem you had is that you have not structured your code properly. Panels should belong to the Frame and should be in sizers. Your code was just placing the about panel on the raw frame and so was appearing as a small square in the top left hand corner - A sure sign that it was not in a sizer.

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title="My Sample App.", size=(1280, 720))

        self.InitMenuBar()
        self.home_panel = HomePanels(self)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.home_panel)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.Show()

    def InitMenuBar(self):
        # Create Menu Bar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        # Create File Menu
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        about_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, 'About', 'Show About')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_about, about_item)
        quit = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit', 'Close')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, quit)

        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Center()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)

    def on_about(self, event):
        # Show the About panel and hide the Main panel
        self._clear_sizer(self.sizer)
        self.about_panel = AboutPanel(self)
        self.sizer.Add(self.about_panel)
        self.Layout()

    def _clear_sizer(self, sizer):
        """Remove all of the widgets from the sizer."""
        for child in sizer.GetChildren():
            if child.IsSizer():
                if child.IsSizer():
                    self._clear_sizer(child.GetSizer())
            else:
                child.GetWindow().Destroy()
        sizer.Clear()


class HomePanels(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Left panel-----------------------------------------------------
        left_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE, size=(250, 600))
        left_panel.SetBackgroundColour('blue')
        main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 1)

        # Right panel-----------------------------------------------------
        right_panel = wx.Panel(self, style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
        right_panel.SetBackgroundColour('#f8f8ff')
        main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 1, wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, 2)

        self.Center()
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Layout()

class AboutPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        about_main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        abt_text = wx.StaticText(self, label="About Panel", pos=(10, 10))
        about_main_sizer.Add(abt_text, 1, wx.EXPAND, 2)

        self.SetSizer(about_main_sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

If you really want to display *About* wouldn't a [dialog](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.dialogs.html) be better or even  [wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo.html)?

Comment: I want to expand from the `about` part. I got stuck here. There will be many other menu items and their own panels.

Comment: Great, It's working! But, is it dynamic, i.e., can it be applied for multiple menuitems where each will open a new panel?

Comment: Can a frame contain a sizer, isn't it placed only inside panels?